# mod_rewrite seems to mess up my ajax post script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, mod-rewrite

my getLikes script that I mentioned in a previous question doesnt work at all when I rewrite the url to a cleaner version...is that b/c it is a Post request? Everything else works fine, like the get part that looks up the user profile.
here is the mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?p=$1 [L]
```

and here is the ajax: it is supposed to get the ID and then posts to a page which returns whether the user likes this profile...its basically a like button

```
public function likesScript($p){?>
    <script>

    //display list of people who like this
    function getLikes(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "likelist.php",

        data: { p: "<?php echo $_GET['p']?>"}
    }).success(function(res) {

        $("#likedBy").html(res); 
        //console.log(res); 

        if($('li#<?PHP echo $_SESSION['userId']; ?>').length){
            $(".Like").hide();
            $(".UnLike").fadeIn();
        } else {  
            $(".UnLike").hide();
            $(".Like").fadeIn();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Look in your browser's network console while the AJAX request happens. What is the HTTP response code, and what errors if any do you see?  Th RewriteRule should not interfere because it does not match `likelist.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `url: "likelist.php"` to `url: "/likelist.php"`.

Use absolute path, URI with everything behind domain name.

http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ **abs_path** [ "?" query ]]

By adding `/` at the beginning or URI, it is nearly equal like you've written `http://example.com/`.

Because you've rewritten URL to `profile/name`, it looks for `profile/name/likelist.php` which clearly doesn't exist.